# Texts to initiate in the theory of homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homotopy-theory, book-recommendation

I want to begin a study of homotopy theory and its applications, I have come across the introductory texts by Arkowitz and Brayton Gray. Particularly, I have found the text of Arkowitz a little more attractive. One of the purposes of this study is to make a kind of article that summarizes the main ideas of homotopy theory. However, there is another concept that catches my attention and it is that of the simplicial homotopy theory, which as far as I know introduces the concept of a homotopy through the simplicial sets.

My question is, is it feasible to try to capture in a small article the introductory aspects of the simplicial homotopy theory, or is it better to make a synthesis with the help of the texts of Arkowitz and Brayton Gray, do you recommend some alternative texts for this purpose?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Goerss-Jardine, simplicial homotopy theory, is a good book

Comment: Could you indicate where we can find the text of Arkowitz in particular ?

Comment: The Arkowitz book is presumably this one: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-7329-0